# How to query Hotmail for new email

Tags: api, email, hotmail

I'm looking for the best way to check if new email has arrived in a Hotmail account without accessing the web interface or using a mail client.

I couldn't find any Hotmail mail API and looking at a Firefox add-on it seems that querying the site through a normal login process and then searching the HTML source is the way to go.

Any suggestions how to do this with security in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for API or plugin?

If API - it looks like they don't have any API for mail, they have API only for contacts and calendar.

But you can use SMTP or POP3 to fetch it.

EDIT

The link to the API can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535).